# How does a method in a parent call a method in a child?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a parent and a child class.

The parent class has two methods that the child overrides.

Here's an example:

```
public class May11 extends May11Parent
{
    public void m1()
    {
        super.m1();
        System.out.println("3");
    }

    public void m2()
    {
        super.m2();
        System.out.println("4");
    }

}

public class May11Parent
{
    public void m1()
    {
        System.out.println("1");
        m2();
    }

    public void m2()
    {
        System.out.println("2");
    }

}
```

Then I have a child object with a parent's reference (main method's in the child class). I execute `m1()` which I know goes to the body of `m1()` of the child. The child calls the parent. The parent calls `m2()`. Magically both `m2()` methods of the child and parent are executed.

My thought was that it's `m2()` of the parent that will be fired. If it's not that of the parent then the child!

I thought it might be about polymorphism but I even tried a child object with a child reference and things are the same. I can't understand what's going on. Any ideas??

Here's a nice screenshot:

[image: Parent-Child weirdness]

Comment: When `m1()` calls `m2()` only the child's `m2()` is called due to polymorphism. But the child's `m2()` calls the parent's `m2()` with `super.m2()` statement. Hence that's called as well.

Comment: There is one important thing to understand when learning programming: there is no **magic**. For most things, there are good deterministic explanations. So the lesson for the newbies can be: if you observe something, try to come up with ideas that explain the observed (instead of assuming that something is "magically broken").

Comment: @Codebender know what this is it! I get it! :D

Comment: @Jägermeister I'm using "magic" to indicate exactly where I lost track. Of course there's nothing broken I'm just trying to understand!

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic here.

First:

The type of the variable referencing the object does only restrict what methods are "visible" at that place. The implementation is still determined by the object instance being referenced.

(Imagine your child class (May11) is specifying an additional `m3()` method. From a variable with parent class type (May11Parent) this would not be callable.)

Second:

the call sequence can easily be determined from the code:

Initially, assume your object reference is bound to variable `var`
(Either of type `May11` or type `May11Parent`)

1. calling `var.m1()`
   This calls `May11.m1()` as the object instance is a `May11`class one.
2. `m1()`is calling `super.m1()`
   This executes `May11Parent.m1()`
3. `May11Parent.m1()` is printing "**1**"
4. `May11Parent.m1()` calls `m2()`
   As the object instance is a `May11` type one, this is executing `May11.m2()`
5. `May11.m2()` is calling `super.m2()` (this is `May11Parent.m2()`)
6. `May11Parent.m2()` is printing "**2**" and returning
7. back at `May11.m2()` next statement is printing "**4**" and returning
8. back at `May11Parent.m1()` this is returning
9. back at `May11.m1()` next statement is printing "**3**" and returning

All resulting from applying the rules of resolving overloaded methods.

Answer (score 1):

This is called *run-time polymorphism* or *dynamic method dispatch*, in [Java The Complete Reference](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00HSO0X6C) (9th edition, page 178) says:

> When an overridden method is called through a superclass reference, Java determines which version of that method to execute based upon the type of the object being referred to at the time the call occurs.

In your example (*I guess this is the confusing part*):

```
public class May11Parent
{
    public void m1() {
        System.out.println("1");
        m2();
    }
// ...
```

When you call `m2()` inside `m1()`  **Java will decide which method will be called based on the type of your object *at runtime*** and, since `x` is a type of `May11`, `m2()` of the child class will be called.

If you follow the flow knowing this, you'll end up with your output: `1 2 4 3`.

Answer (score -3):

This happens due to Polymorphism, if is not that clear what is happening step by step I suggest you to use the Debugger with Toogle Breakpoint
I don't know which IDE you are using but there is this oprion in your's too for sure. 
I use Eclipse, and in Eclipse works like this:
Right click on the line from which you want to follow step by step your execution, and click on "Toogle Breakpoint"
Then click on "Degub As" -> "Java application"
On the top of your screen an yellow arrow will become Enabled, and has the function "Step into"
By clicking on it you can follow step by step what your program is doing, I find that very usefull and could help you to understand better what is happening in your code.

Comment: This doesn't explain what is happening, it only tells the author how to debug to follow the code. I'm voting this as "Not an answer".

Comment: For beginners is really useful, you can check the values of the variables changing step by step
This explains what is happening but not why is happening,
To know why is happening you just have to study, but I think this is a good way to understand the theory applied to practice

Comment: If it's not an answer, post it in a comment rather than an answer. It doesn't matter if it's "useful" or not, if it's not an answer it's not an answer.

Comment: Sorry man, but keep calm... I'm a beginner in Stackoverflow,
By the way the question was
"I can't understand what's going on. Any ideas?"
So this is an answer, next time I will comment...